# How Can Call Sub Dissector in Wireshark on Lua

Tags: lua, wifi, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

In wireshark there is message payload which is actually IEEE 802.11 association request. And i want to show this message as association request format. Normally association request frame parsed in wireshark using "wlan.mgt" dissector. But i can't create desired dissector, like that:

```
local wlan_mgmt_dissector = Dissector.get("wlan.mgt")
```

How can i create "wlan.mgt" dissector and call it?